# How can I retrieve the ip of my access point?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

Originally I had my network as follows. I had a first router creating the 192.168.0.X network, one creating the subnetwork 192.168.1.X and another creating another subnet of 1.X, namely 2.X. The 0 network has most devices attached, but the 2 router has the fastest connection, so I usually connected to 2, but had to change to 0 when I wanted to use upnp-devices as upnp only seems to find devices within the same subnet. **So, I decided to turn the 1 and 2 subnet routers into access points** to create only one home network, namely 0. I first turned the 2 router into an access point with the IP **192.168.1.100** (I thought). Everything worked perfectly, so I decided to turn the middle router into an access point as well with the IP **192.168.0.100**. After I did so, I got quite some bad connections. The speed of the connection dropped way back and couldn't surf to several websites.

Therefore I ended up turning the access points back to routers, to reset the whole thing. The middle router was reset immediately, without any troubles, but now when I connect to the 2 router, I can connect to the internet, so the access point functionality is working, but **I can't seem to access the configuration site**.

The router is a **TP-Link TL-WDR3600** router and the default IP is not working, neither is the tplinklogin.net link. Now **is there a way I can still retrieve the ip for the configuration site?** Can I sniff it out or something? I can use ubuntu, windows or OSX, so it doesn't matter what OS I use to find it.

---

I ran the commands requested by [linuxdev2013](https://superuser.com/users/295176/linuxdev2013) and got the following output:

```
user@PC:~$ nmap 8.8.8.8
Starting Nmap 6.46 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-04-14 21:51 CEST  
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn  
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.05 seconds

user@PC:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table  
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface  
default         dlinkrouter     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0  
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

The router on 1 is the dlink router and I am accessing it through the TP-Link access point, yet it didn't seem to show up.

Comment: `nmap -sP IP_RANGE/MASK` is the `nmap` command to ping sweep; but do you REALLY need that many routers to do what standard networking could do (i.e. subnetting)? Also, flipping your routers to AP's and assigning them all the same IP causes address resolution errors (ping 192.168.1.100 and which AP does it go to??) .. I'm not 100% what you're trying to achieve (some level of "security" through subnetting?), but honestly it sounds like you need to find the best of the 3 wifi routers, do a factory reset, then stick with that one and use the others for extenders (if they can do it and its needed)

Comment: I don't think you read my question completely, because that is exactly what I wanted to do. I don't want to subnet. That's the whole reason I wanted to turn them into access points. They were subnetting before, because that's just how routers work right out of the box. You connect them through WAN and then wirelessly connect to them and internet magically comes to your devices within seconds from opening the box. What I am trying to achieve with 3 routers is, obviously, provide wireless internet throughout my house... Nothing more to it than that.

Comment: @txtechhelp But in the end, turning them into access points really damaged my internet speed. That's why I was reverting back to the initial setup, but somehow I can't seem to connect to one AP's interface to turn DHCP back on.

Comment: Ignore the Interface.  Perform the configuration reset procedure that is documented for your device.  Then reinstall it as a new device.

Comment: Wow. Just wow. If anyone can walk you out of this self-created cesspit of network *eeeeewwww* it might be a miracle worthy of canonization. @Zoredache has the right method to kick the routers upside the head, but what you have been and are doing with them makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Ecnerwal. Its pretty easy. Ill explain. My ISP places a modem creating first subnet. I wanted internet in living room so i pull cable and place router. Then I wanted internet in attic so I placed cable from living room to attic and placed router. All right out of the box providing max speed in the attic wirelessly (200mbps). I wanted to turn routers into AP because it would make sense to do so. I did. Major decrease in speed somehow. So I turned them back. So I could either reset and lose settings or ask you smart people for advice, but yet I get more bashing than anything helpful

Comment: @Zoredache Ill do that. I just wanted to avoid it for as long as I could cos I would lose my settings :( but I guess I have no other choice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [zoredache](https://superuser.com/users/2057/zoredache)'s comment was the way to go.

> Ignore the Interface. Perform the configuration reset procedure that is documented for your device. Then reinstall it as a new device.

When the IP is lost, it doesn't seem like you can find it back. So I guess I should have backed up the settings before attempting to change the router into an Access Point, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get whole-home coverage using a single router configured as a router and two additional routers configured as access points, here's what you do:

1) There should be a setting that you set on each of the routers that enable to to designate the router as an APs. Enable this on your two additional routers.

2) Make sure all three routers have the same Network Name (SSID), security type, and password (every device will be connecting to the external internet via your one main router)

3) Make sure DHCP is off on the two access points (you only want the main router to assign ip addresses). Also, if you are setting any static ip addresses, do that only on the main router. On my network, my access points have static ip addresses assigned in the main router, and DHCP is off so they aren't trying to assign ip addresses to devices that have already been assigned by the main router.

4) Make sure the channel on the router and the two access points are different from each other (e.g. 11, 9, 7). This is where wireless routers can interfere with each other. On separate channels, you are set up to avoid this interference.

I think that's it. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your information. The problem is that the main router would be my ISP's router and that doesnt allow me to assign static IPs. Also I was wondering why you said channels 11 9 and 7. I see those numbers often, but whats special about those channels? They are on automatic now and dont really seem to intervene.

Answer (score 0):

running nmap to some external IP

OR

running:

route

should display the  gateway /ap  addresses (assuming they are up)

Comment: I ran the commands you requested and put the output in the question, but they didn't seem to help though

Comment: I also pinged every IP in the subnet range and got nothing, so ill just reset I guess